# is there a non-fatal equivalent to assert in c?

Tags: c, assert

I would like to write assert statement but not abort the program.  So perhaps use exact same syntax as assert() but called expect().  Of course I can write my own, but assert is quite clever (e.g. it knows not only the file and line number but even the expression which is not TRUE).
I could of course dig into the library and C-v/C-c a solution.
But this is such an obvious generic request I can't believe there is not a good solution already. Which should of course be easily found here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are no such thing. However, it is quite easy to write it  as :

```
#define expect( chk )  \ 
    if (!(chk)) \
        printf("Assertion (%s) failed %s at line %d ", #chk, __FILE__,__LINE__);
```

This test :

```
int main()
{
  expect(0);
  expect(1);

  return 0;
}
```

is going to print the first failed assertion :

```
Assertion (0) failed t.c at line 8
```

[Live demo.](http://codepad.org/HJvrvoha)

Comment: Please don't hide `;` and `if` without `else` inside a macro, this waits for trouble.

Comment: @JensGustedt What do you mean with "hide ; and if without else inside a macro"? How should it be?

Comment: It should be just as in Joachim's answer. Imagine what would happen if you'd use your macro in something like `if (toto()) expect(hu()); else  puts("well well?");` Such macros should also be usable the same way a function call would.

Comment: Thanks. I modified this a little,  to turn off the action when NDEBUG is defined and to write to stderr.  I wrote as a separate answer, not least because my additions may be less good than they appear to me!

Answer (score 9):

It's because `assert` is a preprocessor macro, and so can use the `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` macros as the whole macro invocation is expanded into a single line.

You can easily make your own:

```
#define expect(value, message) \
    do \
    { \
        if (!(value)) \
        { \
            fprintf(stderr, "%s failed in %s:%d\n", #value, __FILE__, __LINE__); \
        } \
    } while(0)
```

Comment: @BЈовић It's an old habit, to make the user of this macro use a semicolon, so the macro invocation looks like a real function call.

Comment: ... and you don't have the problem of an `else` that unexpectedly binds to the `if`.

Comment: `#define expect(value, message) ((void)((value) ? 0 : fprintf(stderr, "%s failed in %s:%d:%s()\n", #value, __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__))` where I'm assuming C99 and the predefined identifier `__func__`.  This could be use in places that your macro couldn't — though I'm open to persuasion that it is not a good idea to allow expectations to be set in expressions as opposed to statements.

Answer (score 2):

With credit to BЈовић

```
#ifdef  NDEBUG
#define expect(chk) ((void *)0)
#else
#define expect(chk) (chk ? (void) (0) : fprintf(stderr,"%s:%d %s: expectation (%s) failed.\n", __FILE__ , __LINE__ , __func__ , #chk))
#endif
```

This version

- writes to stderr, not stdout
- can be disabled like assert() with the NDEBUG macro

It looks as much like the assert() message as possible, though of course it doesn't have the flexibility that assert does in terms of other parameters.

I didn't see why forcing the use of a semicolon is useful - since if there is one it works, and if there isn't it still works!

Some cleverer solution like try...catch around assert() was my hoped for answer, though!

Comment: I would use `((void)0)`, not `((void *)0)`.  No point allowing somebody to use or pass an `expect(something)` as a pointer.

Comment: Re "I didn't see why forcing the use of a semicolon is useful" — Your macro currently "forces the use of a semicolon", which is good, because if you'd accidentally defined it as `#define expect(chk) ((void)0);`, then the statement `if (x) expect(y); else z();` would have failed to compile! (Because it'd expand to `if (x) ((void)0);; else z();` which is a syntax error.)